# Cisco Aironet 1142 reset to default

Tags: cisco, access-point

I have a 1142 that I purchased that needs to be set to factory defaults so that I can configure it. I do an escape at the boot sequence and I get to the

ap:

prompt, the reset instructions that Cisco provides says that I should rename the old config.txt and reboot and that I will then be able to start my reconfig. The problem is that I can't find a config.txt file in the flash space:

Directory of flash:/

```
2  -rwx         260   Jan 1 1970 00:04:28 +00:00  env_vars

3  -rwx      112947   Apr 1 2011 15:17:10 +00:00  event.log

5  drwx         128   Mar 1 2002 00:01:54 +00:00  c1140-rcvk9w8-mx

9  drwx         256   Apr 1 2011 14:30:32 +00:00  c1140-k9w8-mx.124-21a.JHB1

8  -rwx        5144   Mar 1 2002 00:00:27 +00:00  private-multiple-fs
```

I checked in the directories listed above and still found no config.txt. I appreciate all help since I am stuck and can go no further.

Thanks,

Comment: What happens when you continue booting and monitor the console?  Are you presented with the initial configuration dialogue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a AP or LAP (lightweight AP) ? - if I read the IOS right, it's a LAP - and the LAP would have no config of it's own but connect to a controller...

You would need to change the firmware to operate autonomusly...

tsg